# Is it possible to make web only injection with Injectable?

Tags: flutter

I'm using `Injectable` and I have two classes. `WebImageDownloader` and `MobileImageDownloader`. Both are implementing `ImageDownloader` which is an abstract class. I'm registering web and mobile image downloaders as ImageDownloader with Injectable, one [registered under](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable#register-under-different-environments) `web`, one under `mobile` environment.

But since WebImageDownloader has dart:js and dart:html imports, I can't run my code. Because these libraries are not found.

I see on some answers that people do conditional imports between dart:io and dart:html but it doesn't work for me.

Also, the question is under issues for [Injectable](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/injectable/issues/291).

Answer (score -2):

```
import 'MobileFileDownloader.dart'
if (dart.library.html) 'WebFileDownloadService.dart';

abstract class NativeFileDownloader {
  void downloadFile(List<int> bytes, String downloadName);
  factory NativeFileDownloader() =>getDownloader();
}
```

---

```
import 'NativeFileDownloader.dart';

class WebFileDownloadService implements NativeFileDownloader{
   void downloadFile(List<int> bytes, String downloadName) {
    // Encode our file in base64
    final _base64 = base64Encode(bytes);
    // Create the link with the file
    final anchor = AnchorElement(href: 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,$_base64')
      ..target = 'blank'
      ..setAttribute('download', downloadName);
    // add the name
    //anchor.download = downloadName;
    // trigger download
    document.body?.append(anchor);
    anchor.click();
    anchor.remove();
    return;
  }
}
NativeFileDownloader getDownloader()=>WebFileDownloadService();
```

---

```
import 'package:flovo/Services/FileDownloadService/Native/NativeFileDownloader.dart';

class MobileFileDownloader implements NativeFileDownloader{
  @override
  void downloadFile(List<int> bytes, String downloadName) {
  }

}

NativeFileDownloader getDownloader()=>MobileFileDownloader();
```

---

use => NativeFileDownloader().downloadFile(list, 'image.jpeg');

Comment: I already did like this and I have a blog post about it https://mirkan.medium.com/flutter-web-ve-mobil-i%C3%A7in-resim-indirme-kaydetme-1918020deb54

I'm looking for a way to do with Injectable as I posted on the title.

Also: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.